# Is an array of types possible in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use the following pattern in Javascript:

```
var things = {
  "blue": BlueThing,
  "heavy": HeavyThing,
  "imaginary": ImaginaryThing
};

var my_thing = things[thing_type]();
```

I'm migrating the codebase to Typescript, and I can't find a way to achieve the same thing. I've defined a `Thing` interface, and the relevant classes. Is there a way to achieve this sort of dynamic instantiation without resorting to a big `case` statement?

Comment: Object.keys(things)?? just a guess

Comment: @TomMillard The point is I can't create a `things` dictionary in TypeScript since types have no type.

Comment: Typescript is a superset of JavaScript, and **all** valid Javascript is also valid Typescript.  Therefore, it's not really clear what issue you are having, or why this code doesn't work as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I sorted this out.

Using the constructor interface pattern, I now have this:

```
interface ThingConstructor {
  new (options: {[key: string]: string}) : Thing
}

interface Thing{
  /* * */
}

function thingFactory(type: ThingConstructor) : Function{
  return function(options) : Thing {
    return new type(options)
  }
}

--------

things: {[key: string]: Function}

--------

things["blue"] = thingFactory(BlueThing)

var my_thing = things[thing_type]({"stripes": "vertical"})
```

Comment: Maybe specify the function type too? `(options) => Thing`